# R cv.glm returns NaN for stepwise-generated regression model

Tags: r, cross-validation, stepwise-regression

I'm trying to run K-fold cross-validation on a multiple regression model that was generated via the `step` function in R. However, the call to `cv.glm` returns `NaN`.

Here is a simplified script that replicates the problem:

```
# this works just fine
library(boot)
data(mammals, package="MASS")
mammals.glm <- glm(log(brain) ~ log(body), data = mammals)
cv.glm(mammals, mammals.glm, K=5)$delta

# but when I use the step function...
mammals.simple <- lm(("brain ~ 1"), data=mammals)
mammals.glm <- step(mammals.simple, direction="forward", test="F", scope="brain ~ body")
# it returns NaN
cv.glm(mammals, mammals.glm, K=5)$delta
```

Is this due to some fundamental misunderstanding, where it doesn't make sense to cross-validate a stepwise-generated model?

I'm using R v3.0.1 (but 3.1.0 has the same problem).

Comment: Velcome to our site!

Comment: Thanks :) hope this question isn't a misuse. It seems like there's a blurry line between stackoverflow and crossvalidated...

Answer (score 3):

I was running into the same problem but figured out that I was using lm to build the model rather than glm.

From your code above:

mammals.simple <- **glm**(("brain ~ 1"), data=mammals)
mammals.glm <- step(mammals.simple, direction="forward", test="F", scope="brain ~ body")
it returns NaN
cv.glm(mammals, mammals.glm, K=5)$delta

Using your code with glm rather than lm I get:

> cv.glm(mammals, mammals.glm, K=5)$delta
>   [1] 155504.4 146724.9